# jQuery caching JSON response

Tags: jquery

I am using a basic function to do AJAX requests and get a JSON:

```
function getData(endpoint) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: endpoint
    });
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the endpoint could be unresponsive or take too much time to load the data.
In this case I would need to use the latest JSON that I got from the previous call to the endpoint.

I am looking for a way to keep track of the AJAX response time and if it exceeds a given limit of time to use the cached JSON response from the previous request.

Is there an elegant way to do it with jQuery?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: You'd need to 1. save the most recent response somewhere it's going to be accessible, 2. use the `timeout` option for a jQuery AJAX call, 3. handle the case where the request timed out, and execute the callback function with the saved response.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to explain Anthony Gris comment with some sample code

```
var lastResponseData;

function getData(endpoint) {
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    error:function(jqxhr, status){
    if(status==="error"){
      if(lastResponseData!=null){
       //use it
      }
    }
    else
    {
    getData(endpoint); try again
    },
    success:function(data){
     lastResponseData=data;
     //do work
    }

    }
 });
}
```

Comment: In this way it never returns, because the function calling the AJAX request is waiting for the AJAX call to successfully return with $.when function

Answer (score 1):

A variable and deferred objects + a timeout would make this easy:

```
var prevReq = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();

function getData(endpoint) {
    var newReq = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        timeout: 2000
    }).then(function(data){
        // successful, set previous request to this request
        prevReq = newReq;
        return data;
    },function(){
        // it failed, return the previous successful request
        return prevReq;
    });
    return newReq;
}

getData("1").done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/85HNs/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should have functions to handle the diferent results of AJAX, but in the case of success  you shoud store response in a global object, and in the always get data from there, like:

```
GlobalObj = {};
GlobalObj.response = {};

function getData(endpoint) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: endpoint
   })
   .done(function(){ 
   //store in global object
   })
   .fail(function(){})
   .always( function(){
        data = GlobalObj.response;
        //these methods are asyncronous 
        //here you should assing the value instead of returning
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save your last response in the browser cookies.

Take a look at [jQuery cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).